# Google Chrome doesn't open

Tags: google-chrome

My google chrome doesn't open. I got this error..

Google Chrome is having trouble accessing the network.

This may be because your firewall or antivirus software wrongly thinks Google Chrome is an intruder on your computer and is blocking it from connecting to the Internet.
Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings.
If it is already listed as a program allowed to access the network, try removing it from the list and adding it again.
Error code: ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really is a question for the folks over at https://superuser.com/.

You should head over there and ask this question, as Stack Overflow is a place to discuss programming and software development.

The account you have here will also work just fine at Super User, so no need to re-register.

Good luck!